# How Can You Block Twilio Numbers From Registering

Tags: gmail, twilio, asterisk, sip, voip

We have a sensitive service and only want one sign up per person, more or less. We require phone number verification when signing up. Looking into people we've caught creating multiple accounts we see they use twilio numbers, but this is a manual process of looking up the carrier, etc. etc.

Is there a way to automate this and block twilio numbers? I know craigslist and gmail are able to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) to check [carrier details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-carrier-info) about a phone number. Carrier details will include whether Twilio is the carrier.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: While this worked with some of the sample twilio numbers, a lot of them also returned null for the carrier - so this doesn't work good enough. Any other way or a better API by someone else?